# Spring setDisallowedFields is not working

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, testing, spring-mvc-test

The registration controller disallowes sending account id field by the following:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    binder.setRequiredFields("username","password","emailAddress");
} 

@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT })
public String handleRegistration(@ModelAttribute Account account, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "customer/register";
    }
```

I Run the following test to make sure ID is not allowed:

```
@Test
public void testPutRequestWithIdPassedRegistrationController() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/customer/register")
            .param("id", "1")
            .param("username", "shouldBeIgnored")
            .param("password", "123")
            .param("emailAddress", "testIgnored@gmail.com")
            .param("address.country", "RU")
            .param("address.city", "Nsk")
            .param("address.street", "Lenin"))
            .andExpect(model().hasErrors())
            .andExpect(view().name("customer/register"));
}
```

But test fails cause:
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected binding/validation errors

For comparation here is the test that tries to create account without passing not-nullable fields and it passes well, that means that `setRequiredFields` works fine:

```
@Test
public void testPutRequestWithoutNeededFieldsRegistrationController() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/customer/register"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("customer/register"))
            .andExpect(model().hasErrors())
            .andExpect(model().errorCount(3));
}
```

Why does it work by this way? How can I sure that id is not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring does not consider disallowed fields as errors.
It just stores them as `suppressedFields` in the `BindException`.
During debug I could access it via:

```
((BindingResult)getModelAndView(result).getModelMap().get("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.account")).getSuppressedFields()
```

When invoked from the `hasErrors()` method.

So to make sure that id is not used, I just passed it via params and then checked that account with such name (it is a unique field) has another id value:

```
String notExistingId = "999";
String newUserName = "newUser";
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/customer/register")
        .param("id", notExistingId)
        .param("username", newUserName)
        .param("password", "123")
        .param("emailAddress", "testIgnored@gmail.com")
        .param("address.country", "RU")
        .param("address.city", "Nsk")
        .param("address.street", "Lenin"))
        .andExpect(model().hasNoErrors())
        .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/index.htm"));
Optional<Account> account = accountService.getAccount(newUserName);
assertTrue( "Account with the username should exist", account.isPresent());
assertNotSame("Account id should not be equal to the id we try to pass with parameters",
        Long.parseLong(notExistingId),
        account.get().getId());
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined method for getModelAndView().Is it a user defined method? If so what is it expected to do?